# Is there a way to set z-order in the annotation view layer?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I want to have some annotationView images appear on top of the others so they are easier to see. Is there a way to set the order?

I thought I would try something like

```
[theMap addAnnotations:arrayOfLessImportantItems];
[theMap addAnnotations:arrayOfMoreImportantItems];
```

But it is obvious after trying this that the delegate method `MKMapViewDelegate mapView:viewForAnnotation` doesn't observe any particular order when it puts them down. (Since the annotation views come from a pool, the delegate must be adding and removing annotationView images as the map is shifted around on the screen.)

But I do have a small number items that I want to be easier to see, and they are getting buried behind the less important map pins. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7142367/467105).

Answer (score 16):

You could also use the zPosition property from CALayer (you will have to include QuatzCore.h) to change the z-index of the view.

```
yourView.layer.zPosition = 1;
```

Works just the way it would with html/css :)

Comment: I no longer develop for iOS, so I don't know how this behaves in iOS 11