# iOS how to put MKMapView user location marker over annotations?

Tags: ios, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

In my iOS app i am displaying many, big annotations, and i set user location to be shown as well. My problem is, that my markers are so big, they are covering user's position, so it's hidden very often.

My question is - is there any "normal" way to set user location's marker above all the annotations, or i have to display custom annotation for user's position, or else?

Comment: You ever solve this?

Comment: @WillLarche unfortunately - no, still a problem.

Comment: lemme save you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142367/z-index-of-ios-mapkit-user-location-annotation/16357528