# Specifying Z-index for Map Markers and Annotations

Tags: swift, swiftui-map

Using SwiftUI, MapKit and the `Map()` view in iOS 17, I'm adding markers and annotations to the map instance. However it seems regardless of what order they are added, they are rendered with random Z-index values. I've not found any modifiers to specify any kind of priority.

Is there a way to declare Z-index priority of `Marker` and `Annotation` views?

Comment: When I was developing an app for iOS in 2017 using Swift, I found there was no way to specify the Z value.  I'm just developing a new app using KMP and have searched to see if Apple has bothered to fix this and found your query. Apparently not! Pathetic.

Although, see here (down the bottom):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142367/z-index-of-ios-mapkit-user-location-annotation

Comment: In the past there has been a priority property I've used that has allowed my code to influence Z-index. But here I'm talking about SwiftUI, specifically the new implementation of the MapKit Map() in iOS 17. I would imagine this support will come in a future version.